# How to draw Hasse diagram for partially ordered set

Tags: order-theory

How would you draw a Hasse diagram. When $P = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $\subset$ is the subset relation: $A \subset B$ if and $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. How many edges does the cover graph of the poset $(P, \subset)$ have?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Did you take a look at Wikipedia yet?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram#A_%22good%22_Hasse_diagram

Comment: there are four versions of the same Hasse diagram in the previous link, all of that poset. You must figure out how these labellings relate to the case you want

Comment: How can you find the edges in this case? @amrsa

Comment: Is it like this as I created ? https://ibb.co/kJTjqn

Comment: No, the elements are the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and one element is below other if it is contained in it. Did you take a look at the linked images?

Comment: It's like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) (ignore the colors).

Comment: Thanks, so how many edges does the cover graph of the poset (P, ⊂) have? @amrsa

Comment: If you're asking how many edges are there in the poset, just count them (there must be 32). If you're talking about [edge covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) of graphs, then you should ask this question with the 'graph-theory' tag, but it seems to me that a minimum edge cover has 8 edges (if we only count the edges of the Hasse diagram, not of the whole order relation as a graph).

Comment: @amrsa, Thanks, I understand. I need to find out. How many  total edges does the cover graph of the poset have?

Comment: I answered that question in the previous comment. I think the minimum is 8. I mean, if I understood the concept right, which I believe I did. How did I come up with this number? Well, the poset has 16 elements, and given its symmetry, it is possible to cover those with 8 edges if each vertex is only adjacent to one edge.

Comment: Yes I understand @amrsa. But you know there is a different condition.

Comment: P={1,2,3,4}  and ⊂ is the subset relation: A⊂B if and A is a proper subset of B.